# HTML5 set image and text label in the center of web page

Tags: css, html

I need help with HTML / .css

I am trying to setup Image and Text in the center of Web Form Page. Also Image should be on the left of Text.

I've tried 2 solutions, but when I create table - it display on the left of screen and can't go middle.

[image: sample]

## A

```
<section class="main-page">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" Height="35px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Origin/logo.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1><%: Title %></h1>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</section>
```

## B

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><h1><%: Title %></h1></th>
            <th><asp:Image ID="Image2" Height="35px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Origin/logo.jpg" /></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## .css

```
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*max-width: 960px;*/
}
```

Comment: Please note that `hgroup` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the image/text in a container with `text-align:center;` defined in order for them to be centred, then the text should simply precede the image.

If for whatever reason the `img` element cant be placed *following* the text, you may need to `float` the elements to rearrange their ordering.

If the text is within a block level element, you will also need to set `display:inline-block` on it

As a basic demo:

HTML

```
<section>Text
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdw26b_dwa8moS-gRSFpaG3dwJTB6Nqtqxexmb7PscuD5gVP-P' />
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:Center;
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle of example A](http://jsfiddle.net/CaR8K/1/)

HTML

```
<section class="main-page">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdw26b_dwa8moS-gRSFpaG3dwJTB6Nqtqxexmb7PscuD5gVP-P' />
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
div, section{
    display:inline-block;
}
div:first-child{
    float:right;
}
div:last-child{
    float:left;
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle of example B](http://jsfiddle.net/CaR8K/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><h1>Title</h1></th>
            <th><img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdw26b_dwa8moS-gRSFpaG3dwJTB6Nqtqxexmb7PscuD5gVP-P' /></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
table{
    display:inline-block;
}
```